# Swap my logo image on scroll (Modify existing script)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a theme I'm working on the HubSpot COS. There is some js for a "sticky" header.

```
function stickyHeader( logoheight, logowidth ) {

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            var distanceY = $(window).scrollTop();
            var shrinkOn = 100;
            var header = $( '.header-container-wrapper' );
            var logo = $( '.header-container-wrapper img' );

            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                if ( !header.hasClass( 'sticky' ) ) {
                    var logowith_sm = ~~ ( logowidth / logoheight * 55 );
                    logo.transition({height: '55px', width: logowith_sm + 'px'}, 300)
                }
                header.addClass( 'sticky' );
            } else {
                if ( header.hasClass( 'sticky' ) ) {
                    if ( distanceY <= shrinkOn ) {
                        logo.transition({height: logoheight + 'px', width: logowidth + 'px'}, 300)
                    }
                    header.removeClass( 'sticky' );
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

I see that with this script, if the header has the "sticky" class it changes the image height to `55px`. Is there something I could add to this script that would change the actual image url at the same time?

I want to change the logo image for "sticky" because the header background color changes and I want to just replace the existing full color logo with a plain white one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .attr() function on the 'logo' jQuery object:

```
logo.attr('src', '<new image url>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing an image src attribute can be glitchy and won't always be a smooth transition.
I would highly recommend you look into making a sprite containing your full colour logo and your white logo.
Then inside your scroll event simply change the background-position attribute.
You can learn more about using sprites here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Heres an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wxbd29ww

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/sprite/w_150,h_60,c_fit/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 52px;
}
.logo.change {
  background-position: 0 -116px;
}
```

Comment: how would that look in the script? `logo.attr('background-position', 'XXpx 0');` ?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a fiddle. Hope it helps.